# Hold Pushbutton for soft latch after X seconds

Tags: timer, 555, button

What I'm trying to achieve is have a momentary push button that must be held for say 5 seconds before latching on permanently.

But the button must be held for entire duration or else timer will reset.

I'm looking at 555 timers but struggling to figure out how to auto reset on button release before timer finished.

Comment: And how do you then unlatch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

[image]

S1 is normally ON. It keeps C1 discharged via the output of comparator U1.

When S1 is pressed continuously long enough, C1 gets charged to Vref. The comparator output jumps high. It stays latched because releasing S1 does not suck C1 empty.

Pressing S2 resets the circuit. R4 is only small, say 100 Ohm. It prevents the spark in S2. R3 can be for ex. 47 kOhm and R5 a few, say 2 kOhm.

Comparator U1 must have open collector output. It cannot drive any substantial load. You need for it a mosfet or other high current gain buffer circuit.

**Not asked:**

Like your 555, it uses only about 40 years old technology and is totally free of software problems, computer viruses, need of web connection, subscription payments etc...

Answer (score 1):

This can be done the old way by charging and discharging a cap into a comparator.  However, it only takes two parts to do this with current technology.  That will take less board space, is more flexible when the inevitable changes are required, more accurate, and about the same cost.

Use something like a PIC 10F200.  That's a tiny microcontroller that comes in a SOT-23 package.  That's the same package used by small discrete transistors.  It costs about $.25 in quantity.

Connect the button between one of the inputs and ground.  Enable the internal pullup on that input.  In firmware, whenever the input is high (button released), reset a timer to your 5 second delay time.  Whenever the input is low (button pressed), count down.  When the timer gets to 0, assert the output.

The reason I say this solution is two parts instead of just one is because there should be a bypass cap across Vdd to Vss of the micro.